# StarUML class diagram: add attribute of the type Guid[]

Tags: class-diagram, staruml

In StarUML 5.0, I am trying to define a class with an attribute of the type Guid[] (an array of Guid Structure). But it is not allowable to enter "-guids : Guid[]" since StarUML automatically discards the square brackets.

I have not tried other modeling tools...just want to know how to do this with StarUML.

StarUML seems to accepts if I provide the length of the array, like "-guids : Guid[10], but in the code generated by StarUML, this field is something like

```
private Guid guids; //the square brackets are missing;
```

Or I can add an asterisk like "-guids : Guid*", in the code generated, the field is like this

```
private Guid* guids;
```

this is not what i want neither, even with the fact that in C++ a pointer and an array is conceptually interchangeable. (I am coding in C#)

Comment: Consider changing the title to be more general so more people can find this. Perhaps "How do I add array attribute to class in StarUML?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

StarUML defines arrays a little differently to standard UML. For your specific problem I would use [*] to define the array. The first example below describes this.

*Define an array with an undefined number of elements:*

```
-guids: Guid[*]
```

*Define an array with a specific number of elements:*

```
-guids: Guid[16]
```

*Define a base 0 array with an undefined number of elements:*

```
-guids: Guid[0..*]
```

*Define a base 1 array with an undefined number of elements:*

```
-guids: Guid[1..*]
```

*Define a specific base array with a specific number of elements:*

```
-guids: Guid[1..100]
```

Comment: I've had a look at the Code Generation process for all the languages. It seems that none of the languages are generated correctly. StarUML will always leave the [ ] out of the declaration.