# StarUML class diagram: add attribute of the type int [][]

Tags: java, matrix, staruml

I am having problems modeling matrixes of a not defined number of places in StarUML... I've read in a previous question that, to add an array as an attribute, you have to write:

```
array: int[*]
```

After seeing that, I tried:

```
matrix: int[][]

matrix: int[ * ][ * ]

matrix: int[ * ][ ]

matrix: int[ ][ * ]
```

But none worked. They all sent a wrong syntax error popup. Does anyone know what the correct syntax would be?

Comment: Have you looked into this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949622/staruml-class-diagram-add-attribute-of-the-type-guid